# Why do I have to include .c_str() in C++ for finding string length?

Tags: c-strings, string-length, strlen

Since C is a subset of C++
Why can't I use
int y=strlen(S);
instead of 
int y=strlen(S.c_str());
in my C++ program.
Why is it necessary to convert the string to a C string?

PS:
I know other methods of extracting string length exist like
int y=S.length();
But int x=temp.S.length(); seems more complicated and prone to syntax errors than
int x=strlen(temp.S);

This confuses me as I recently shifted from C to C++

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using strlen() at all in `c++`? Use `S.length()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen` function accepts as a parameter a `const char *` not an `std::string`. These are two different types for C++ compiler. It differs from C-compiler since it supports function overloading and strictly checks types of parameters. To that end `c_str()` method of `std::string` class returns the required pointer to make it compatible with legacy functions such as `strlen`.

Also it is worth mentioning that it may have been implemented in such a way that it could have supported implicit conversion to `const char *` so developer would have not required to call `c_str()` method every time he wanted this functionality. This aspect has been specifically addressed by the inventor of C++ Bjarne Stroustrup in his detailed book *C++ programming language*:

> Conversion to a C-style string could have been provided by an operator
>   const char*() rather than c_str(). This would have provided the
>   convenience of an implicit conversion at the cost of surprises in
>   cases in which such a conversion was unexpected.